# Autocorrelation of discontinuous time series data

Tags: python, dataset, autocorrelation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am attempting to perform an autocorrelation study using python on a discontinuous time series dataset. To share a bit about how my data looks like, it is a single column of values, which spans over 18 time slots per day, for multiple days.

My problem is that if I use the "traditional" autocorrelation function plot found in the statsmodels package to compute the autocorrelation with the first lag for example, I fear that the first slot of the 2nd day will have as its first lag the 18th (last) slot of the previous day.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Should I compute the autocorrelation for each day on its own and then average the values? Or is there another way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Are the time slots unevenly or evenly spaced across each day?

Answer (score 1):

An estimate of autocovariance of order $j$ is
$$
\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=j+1}^T(x_t-\bar x)(x_{t-j}-\bar x)
$$
where $\bar x:=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_t$ is an estimate of $\mathbb{E}(X)$. (The can be some variation in the denominator of $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$; $T$ is not the only choice.) An estimate of autocorrelation of order $j$ is
$$
\hat\rho(j)=\frac{\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)}{\widehat{\text{Cov}}(0)}.
$$
You seem to be interested in replacing $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$ with
$$
\widehat{\widetilde{\text{Cov}}}(j)=\frac{1}{T-\ell}\sum_{t\in I(j)}(x_t-\bar x)(x_{t-j}-\bar x)
$$
where $I(j)$ is the set of pairs $(x_t,x_{t-j})$ where both $x_t$ and $x_{t-j}$ belong to the same day. Thus, the sum in $\widehat{\widetilde{\text{Cov}}}(j)$ is based on that in $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$ but omits the elements where $x_t$ and $x_{t-j}$ belong to different days. $\ell$ accounts for the omitted elements, and I am not sure what exactly it should be... Maybe just the number of elements excluded from $\widehat{\widetilde{\text{Cov}}}(j)$ relative to $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$?

$\widehat{\widetilde{\text{Cov}}}(j)$ can be calculated manually; it should not be too difficult to code. It may be possible to come up with a trick that would allow using the usual function of estimating covariance with minimal changes, but I do not have any concrete idea for it now.

You have suggested an option of averaging $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$ from every day. This would use a different $\bar x_\tau$ every day (where $\tau$ indicates the day) and would be less efficient than using $\bar x$ defined above, unless you think $\mathbb{E}(X)$ varies from day to day. E.g. in the case of $j$ close to 18, I suspect $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(j)$ would be poorly behaved.

Comment: The variation in the denominator (subtracting $j$) is not unimportant, the variant you propose is not guaranteed to be positive defnite.

Comment: @JarleTufto, do you know if there is a standard/dominant version? I have seen different versions, so I was really unsure which one to post.

Comment: All textbooks I've seen has only $n$ (the length of the series) in the denominator, e.g. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-0320-4, definition 1.5.2.  https://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN6833/lectures/wwts-book.pdf discusses $n-j$ but notes that that estimator is not necessarily non-negative definite.

Answer (score 0):

Standard autocorrelation is always computed by time periods, lag 1 is the previous period whatever calendar time meaning it has.

One problem is missing data or unequal time spacing. In that case the standard autocorrelation computation just takes the previous available data point.

Another possible problem is unequal season lengths. For example, daily data computes autocorrelation by day lags. There is no autocorrelation for day of the month. The autocorrelation would be, for example, for a 30 days lag, but not autocorrelation between observation on the first, or 31st days of the month.

Comment: For my data, all my days are divided into exactly 18 time slots (18 data points), so there is no problem of missing data or unequal season lengths. My only concern is that the standard autocorrelation function will compare 2 slots from different days (last slot of first day and first slot of 2nd day), when they should not be really compared, since they are assumed to be 2 different days.

Comment: @Sam I misunderstood that part. The autocorrelation definition assumes a single time series, so it will compute the lagged correlation across days as in (last slot of first day and first slot of 2nd day).  AFAIK, statsmodels does not have a function that only estimates within day/trial autocorrelation. related issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4145